# Python Rule Engine for Scoring

Tags: python

I'm implementing a rules scoring system in Python. Each element starts with a score of 100 and deductions are made based on a set of rules.

Instead of doing like below, is there a cleaner way of accomplishing this by using some type of rules library in Python?

```
def get_score(element):
    score = 100

    if rule_1_match(element):
        score -= 50
    
    if rule_2_match(element):
        score -= 20

    if rule_3_match(element):
        score -= 25

    if rule_4_match(element):
        score -= 10

    # Min score is 0 so we take the max of 0 and the score
    return max(score, 0)
```

Comment: I'd have each rule function return the score adjustment; then all your need to do is store the functions in a list and run through it, `score = 100; for rule in rules: score += rule(item)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could arrange your rules and their scores as a list of tuples:

```
rules = [(rule_1_match, 50), (rule_2_match, 20), ...]
```

And then iterate the list of rules and deduct the matching score:

```py
def get_score(element):
    score = 100

    for rule, deduct_score in rules:
        if rule(element):
            score -= deduct_score

    # Min score is 0 so we take the max of 0 and the score
    return max(score, 0)
```